# XSLT Remove parent and keep children, rename grandparent, and sort children in a given order

Tags: xslt

I have a large number of html files with the following structure:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>t</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="z">
      <div class="m">m1</div>
      <div class="y">
        <div class="a">a1</div>
        <div class="b">b1</div>
        <div class="x">
          <div class="a">a2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="c">c1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="n">n1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="y">
      <div class="c">c2</div>
      <div class="d">d1</div>
      <div class="x">
        <div class="a">a3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="b">b2</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to:

1. Remove all div class="x" but keep its content; div class="x" have no text nodes
2. Rename all div class="y" to div class="x"; div class="y" have no text nodes
3. Order the nodes inside div class="x" in a specific order (not necessarily alphabetical): a, b, c, any other.
4. If there is more than one div class="a" there is no preference of their order; same for div class="b", div class="c", any other.

The final output should be like the following:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>t</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="z">
      <div class="m">m1</div>
      <div class="x">
        <div class="a">a1
        <div class="a">a2
        <div class="b">b1
        <div class="c">c1
      </div>
      <div class="n">n1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="x">
      <div class="a">a3
      <div class="b">b2
      <div class="c">c2
      <div class="d">d1
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I utilise a shell script similar to the following:

```
xsltproc a.xslt a.html > b.html
```

where a.xslt is the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="div[@class='x']" >
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()" />
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="div[@class='y']" >
  <div class="x">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()" />
  </div>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My output is almost there, but the nodes are not in order: a, b, c, any other.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>t</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="z">
      <div class="m">m1</div>
      <div class="x">
        <div class="a">a1</div>
        <div class="b">b1</div>
        <div class="a">a2</div>
        <div class="c">c1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="n">n1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="x">
      <div class="c">c2</div>
      <div class="d">d1</div>
      <div class="a">a3</div>
      <div class="b">b2</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to sort them in the correct order?

Are step 1 and 2 the correct approach to get this type of output, or should I use a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this will entirely suit your needs, but try this alternative template for matching `div[@class='y']`

```
<xsl:template match="div[@class='y']" >
  <div class="x">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::div[@class='x'])]|div[@class='x']/*">
     <xsl:sort select="@class" />  
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </div>
 </xsl:template>
```

This selects all child nodes of the div that are not `@class="x"`, and also the direct child nodes of any divs that are `@class="x"`

You might be able to remove the template that matches `div[@class='x']` in this case.

Comment: Thank you Tim. That's a better approach. It seems to be working now.